# Nginx exclude from access log an URL using map and regex to catch a part of word in URL

Tags: regex, nginx, pcre

I have Nginx 1.17 with config what successfully excludes POST request method from logging

```
map $request_method $loggable {
default       1;
POST          0;
}
access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx_access.log main if=$loggable;
```

I try config below to exclude from logging any URL where is a part of word "rsey" with case-insensitive matching , for example JerSey2018

```
map_hash_bucket_size 128;
map $request_uri $loggable {
    (.*?)rsey(.*?) 0;
    default 1;
    }
map $request_method $loggable {
default       1;
POST          0;
}
access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx_access.log main if=$loggable;
```

But with this config NGINX still excludes POST requests from logging, but still write to log where URL like
http://example.com/ID-16409696108601-JerSey2018-report.html
so my map/regex rule does not catch what necessary - LOG EXAMPLE ->

```
example.com 88.256.54.27 - - [01/Aug/2019:06:52:00 -0500]  "GET /ID-16409696108601-JerSey2018-report.html HTTP/1.1" 200 3366 "http://example.com/sitemap.xml" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393"
```

Thx for any hints and ideas to try...may be somebody could point me to an error in the config above ?

***A little later - so tired to fight with Nginx map it seems better to catch location by part of a word using something like that (although does not work too)

```
location ~ /(.*)rsey(.*)/ {
    access_log off;
 }
```

So now thx for any ideas what try here to catch REAL wildcard in Nginx in this line

```
location ~ /(.*)rsey(.*)/ {
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the same variable from two `map` blocks. But you can use the value of the first `map` as the default value of the second.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $loguri {
    default  1;
    ~*rsey   0;
}
map $request_method $loggable {
    default  $loguri;
    POST     0;
}
access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx_access.log main if=$loggable;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

Comment: To my regret doesn't work, situation is the same, I have played with all possible variations but same result. Could you give an example without POST ? Let's leave only one map regex to catch a part of a word and exclude from log...thx in advance

Comment: I only just noticed that the text you are trying to match contains an uppercase `S`. Use either `~rSey` or `~*rsey`